# Using HEX values in a Case statement

Tags: arduino, hex, case

Hi I am trying to use a remote for a project I am doing. I have input the remote HEX values within the case statement, however I am getting an error that states 'error: duplicate case value'. I am assuming its because the HEX values all begine with 0x.This is not my code as I am not at that level of coding to code this myself yet so I am using someone else code, however the values they had in their code was 2 digit numbers but my remote outputs HEX values, or is there a way I can get an 2 digit readout from my remote?

Below is the code I am using in my project with the HEX values.(Not the start to finish code but the bit that uses the HEX values). This project is being used on an arduino and I am using the arduino IDE to compile this.

```
void monitorIR(){
  if(IrReceiver.decode()){
    int ircommand = IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command;
    Serial.println(ircommand);
    Serial.println(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.decodedRawData, HEX);
    IrReceiver.resume();
      
    if(lastCommandReceived!=ircommand){
        lastCommandReceived = ircommand;

        //When you press a button on your remote you should see values showing up in the Serial Monitor...
        switch(ircommand){
            // IR UP BUTTON - OPEN FACE
            case 0xE718FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT 
            if(facePlateCurMode == FACEPLATE_CLOSED){
                facePlateOpenFx();
            }
            break;
            // IR DOWN BUTTON - CLOSE FACE
            case 0xAD52FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT 
            if(facePlateCurMode == FACEPLATE_OPEN){
                facePlateCloseFx();                    
            }     
            break;
            // IR BUTTON 1 - TURN ON EYES
            case 0xBA45FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT 
            if(facePlateCurMode == FACEPLATE_CLOSED){
                ledEyesOn();
            }
            break;
            // IR BUTTON 2 - TURN OFF EYES
            case 0xB946FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT 
            if(facePlateCurMode == FACEPLATE_CLOSED){
                ledEyesOff();
            }
            break; 
            //PLAYING ADDITIONAL SOUNDS
            // IR BUTTON 3 
            case 0xB847FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT 
                playSoundEffect(SND_JARVIS_EXTRA_A);
            break; 
            // IR BUTTON 4  
            case 0xBB44FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT 
                playSoundEffect(SND_JARVIS_EXTRA_B);
            break; 
            // IR BUTTON 5    
            case 0xBF40FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT 
                playSoundEffect(SND_JARVIS_EXTRA_C);
            break; 
            // IR BUTTON 6 
            case 0xBC43FF00:  // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT      
                playSoundEffect(SND_JARVIS_EXTRA_D);
            break; 
            // IR BUTTON 7  
            case 0xF807FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT      
                playSoundEffect(SND_JARVIS_EXTRA_E);
            break; 
            // IR BUTTON 8 
            case 0xEA15FF00: // <--- CHANGE THE # IF DIFFERENT      
                playSoundEffect(SND_JARVIS_EXTRA_F);
            break; 
        }
         
    } 
  }
}
```

`Below is the code I used to get the readout from the remote before inputting the value into the above code.`

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <IRremote.hpp>

const int IR_RECEIVE_PIN = 13;
//const int redPin = 10;

//decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  IrReceiver.begin(IR_RECEIVE_PIN, true); // Start the receiver
  //pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if (IrReceiver.decode()) {
    Serial.println(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.decodedRawData, HEX);
    IrReceiver.printIRResultShort(&Serial);

    switch(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.decodedRawData)
    {
      case 0xE31CFF00: //Keypad button "5"
        Serial.println("5");
        //digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
        delay(2000);
        //digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    IrReceiver.resume(); // Enable receiving of the next value
  }
}
```

Any pointers or help would be great.

Many Thanks,

Matt

I have looked online but I cannot find anyone having this issue or using HEX within Case statment so I am at a lose how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: if it is a 8-bit Arduino then int is only two bytes. your codes have 4 bytes

Comment: See above comment.  If your `int` is 16-bit (read the datasheet for the Arduino part you're using), then these 32-bit ints that represent IR commands just won't work.  You can try redeclaring `ircommand` as either `long` or `unsigned long` as a starting point.  Looks like the code you're using was from either a larger type Arduino, or a more general-purpose CPU/MCU in which `int` is (at least) 32 bits long.

Comment: I have tried this on multiple device, Arduino uno R3, ardunio Nano and an arduino Pro mini and none of these have worked.

Comment: 1) The working sample does not reduce the switch variable to a wrong data type.
2) Your devices are all 8bit controllers. 
3) Data type `int` signals that you do not really care about its size, which is wrong here.
4) your question is not about the HEX notation.

Answer (score 0):

`switch(i)` behaves differently depending on the data type of i

```
uint32_t i = 54321;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 switch (i) {
  case 0x10001: Serial.println(0x10001, HEX); break;
  case 0x20001: Serial.println(0x20001, HEX); break;
  default: Serial.println(i, HEX); break;
 }
}

void loop() { }
```

This works well, but if i is a 16bit int, the case constants are treated as 16bit as well, cutting off the higher parts and resulting in duplicate cases

Comment: what would be the smallest microcontroller I could use for this code?

Comment: Any arduino would do, if you do it right. `int` is wrong. `uint32_t`is the proper type, supported by any arduino controller I know.